# Размер загружаемого файла

Tags: php

Необходимо запретить пользователю загружать файл размером более 5 МБ. В условие используются байты. 5 МБ это 5e+6 байт. Но PHP требует целое число.

Comment: Покажите ваш код, которым проверяете размер загружаемого файла

Comment: 5 * 1024 * 1024

Answer (score 1):

Измените настройки `php.ini`, добавьте параметр `upload_max_filesize = 5М`.

Comment: а зачем в конфигурации что то  менять ? не легче просто проверить через PHP ? )))

Comment: Можно исправить htaccess ) думаю что так будет проще

Comment: Нет конечно )) " ЗАЧЕМ СТРЕЛЯТЬ ИЗ ПУШКИ ПО ВОРОБЬЯМ ?" в обработчике загрузки можно просто  проверить размер загружаемого файла и если он больше  5М - ничего не делать (или что то сделать), я так стараюсь вас натолкнуть на верный путь и возможно вы отредактируйте свой ответ и напишите пример, как можно через PHP проверить размер файла....

Comment: @Arsen, а максимальный размер загружаемого файла по умолчанию всего 2М ;)

Comment: @Visman, совершенно с вами согласен )), по дефолту upload_max_filesize  установлен в 2М, но вопрос же не об этом ? не думаю что вопрос надо расшифровывать как анаграмму.. цитирую >Необходимо запретить пользователю загружать файл размером более 5 МБ,  из вопроса становится очевидным, что на сервере уже установлен больший лимит загрузки файлов, а вот исполнителю необходимо запретить загрузку если больше 5М ))))

Comment: Я возможно некорректно выразился. upload_max_filesize изменён. Мне необходимо выставить свою ошибку при загрузке файла более 5 МБ, а не серверную. Комментарий Visman'a ответил на вопрос.

Comment: я б на вашем месте провалидировал размер на стороне клиента сначала, чтобы в принципе исключить лишний траффик на сервер.

Answer (score 0):

```
if((int)filesize('img.jpg')>5000000)
```

Comment: Проверять размер *уже загруженного* файла — довольно бесполезное занятие.

Comment: Стоит метка php в вопросе, т.е. проверять нужно на сервере уже загруженный файл. Какие могут быть альтернативы...

Comment: В вопросе нет ни слова про *загруженный* файл. Вопрос про *загружаемый* файл — тот, которого на сервере ещё не существует и который не должен существовать, если он слишком большой.

Comment: В вопросе четко сказано "php требует число", т.е. нужен инструмент на php, вот и получайте...

Comment: В вопросе четко сказано «Размер **загружаемого** файла», а не загруженного.

Comment: Загружаемый становится загруженным и проверяется. Вы уже просто к словам придирается. И вообще по вашей логике, если запрещать загрузку в настройках сервера, пользователь не поймет, почему файл не загрузился, а если на клиенте запрещать, то это можно легко обойти

Comment: А файл окажется размером несколько терабайт и в процессе загрузки полностью забьёт свободное место на сервере. Нет, вариант с «загруженным» категорически не годится

Comment: В php.ini уже по умолчанию итак стоит ограничение, вопрос в том чтобы отправить пользователю ответ, что файл большой. Пишите такие комментарии под вопросом. В нем стоит метка php.

Comment: В вопросе ничего не сказано про ответ пользователю, это вы уже сами придумали. Правильным ответом на вопрос в его текущей формулировке является настройка этого самого php.ini, о чём и написано в соседнем ответе.

Comment: А вообще автор вопроса всего лишь не смог правильно записать число 5 МБ в своём коде. Так что из-за капитальной мутности вопроса и сумбурности имеющихся ответов я проголосовал за его закрытие на всякий случай